# How to extend a class property inherited from parent class in ES6?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have the follow code:

```
class Parent {
    some_class_property = [1,2,3];

    some_other_methods(){...}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    some_class_property = super.some_class_property.push(4);
}
```

The console gives me a syntax error, saying that the keyword `super` is unexpected.

If class properties are allowed in ES6, then what's the point not allowing it to be extended in child classes? If this is not the right way to do it, then how? Thanks.

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/beginners-guide-to-mobile-web-development/super-and-extends-in-javascript-es6-understanding-the-tough-parts-6120372d3420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `super` references are not permitted inside class fields, which is why your current code throws an error.

But, the `some_class_property` is put onto the *instantiated object itself* in the superclass constructor (well, in the class field, which is effectively syntax sugar for putting it onto the object in the superclass constructor), which means you can reference it in the child class by referencing `this.some_class_property`. You aren't referencing a shadowed method or property, so `super` isn't needed:

```js
class Parent {
  some_class_property = [1, 2, 3];
}

class Child extends Parent {
  some_class_property = this.some_class_property.push(4)
}

const c = new Child();
console.log(c.some_class_property);
```

Also keep in mind that `.push` returns the new length of the array, which is why the result of the above snippet is `4`. (If you wanted to make a copy of the `some_class_property` array, for whatever reason, instead use `some_class_property = [...this.some_class_property, 4]`)

The time to use `super` is when a property exists on the child instance, or the child prototype, but you want to reference a property on the parent prototype, eg:

```js
class Parent {
  method() {
    console.log('parent method');
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  method() {
    console.log('child method');
  }
  invokeParentMethod() {
    super.method();
  }
}

const c = new Child();
c.method();
c.invokeParentMethod();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on `this` in `this.some_class_property`? Does it refer to the instance, child class, or the parent class itself?

Comment: When the child class field runs, it looks up `this.some_class_property` and finds that the instance itself has a `some_class_property` own property, which was assigned in the superclass's class field. Then, in `some_class_property =`, it overwrites that same own property with the new value.

Comment: When the child field runs, the instance creation has just started and therefore there should be a instance, right? I think I'm still confused about which comes after which. Your asnwer is great, I just could use a little more clarification here.

Comment: The superclass constructor / class field assigns to a property directly on the instance, right before the subclass constructor / class field runs. So, the subclass class field, if it references `this.some_class_property` as a getter, will successfully retrieve the value set directly onto the instance by the superclass's class field, which just ran. (Superclass constructors / class fields always run before a subclass's)

Comment: so class constructor and class field both run after the creation of an instance?

Comment: The instance is just what `this` (in both the constructor and class field, in both the subclass and superclass) references. When `new <someClass>` is called, an empty object whose internal prototype is the subclass prototype is created. Then, the superclass constructor / class fields run. Then, the subclass constructor / class fields run.

Answer (score 0):

Public and private properties are Javascript features at an experimental stage (ES11?). For the past few years for ES6, people have been doing this:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(x){
        this.property1 = [1,2,3];
        ...
    }
    some_other_methods(){...}
}
Parent.property2 = [4,5,6];                 // to access: Parent.property1
Parent.prototype.property3 = [7,8,9];       // to access: obj.property2

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(x){
        super(x);
        // ...
    }
    some_other_methods(){...}
}
```